# Get the rows of a matrix using another matrix

Tags: matrix, octave, addressing

I'm trying to find a vectorized way to do the following -

```matlab
X =
   0   1
   5   5
  -1   8

> w=[false true; true false; false true]  
w = 
      0  1
      1  0
      0  1
```

I want to index into `X`'s rows using the columns of `w`, so the first column of `w` should retrieve row `2` of `X`, and the second column of `w` should retrieve rows `1` and `3` of `X`, and the result would be a single row matrix `[5 5]`, and another matrix `[0 1; -1 8]`, each of which I can then take `mean()` on to get `[5 5]`, and `[-0.5 4.5]` (ideally forming a matrix `[5 5; -0.5 4.5]`).

How can I do this without loops?
My gut feeling is it's possible by converting `X` into a 3D matrix, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following one-liner:

```matlab
bsxfun(@rdivide, w'*X, sum(w)')
```

Result:

```matlab
ans =

   5.00000   5.00000
  -0.50000   4.50000
```

`bsxfun` is your friend!

**Explanation**

`w'*X` generates a matrix whose rows are each a sum of the specified rows of `X`:

```matlab
> w'*X
ans =

   5   5
  -1   9
```

However, you want the average, not the sum.
For that, we should divide each row by the number of elements that were summed together.
The operation `sum(w)'` generates a vector whose `i`-th element is the number of `1`s in the `i`-th column of `w`, i.e., the number of rows of `X` added together in the `i`-th row of `w'*X`:

```matlab
> sum(w)'
ans =

   1
   2
```

Now we want to divide the first by the second, and we use `bsxfun` to broadcast the division operation (`rdivide`, i.e., element-by-element right division `./`) so that the dimensions of `w'*X` and `sum(w)'` match.

Some useful references:

- [Broadcasting](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Broadcasting.html)
- [`rdivide`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFrdivide)

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`, which returns the indices of nonzero entries of a given vector. For example,

```
X(find(w(:,1)), :)
```

returns [5   5]

Similarly, `X(find(w(:, 2)), :)` returns

```
   0   1
  -1   8
```

You can then proceed with the mean, etc, and eventually stack the resulting matrices vertically like `C = [A; B]`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested in knowing if there's a way to do this without using a loop over the columns of w, by maybe expanding X into a 3D matrix, and some clever use of bsxfun()?